# Month February is getting parsed as '33' in the below program. How to fix?

Tags: java, date-format

In the below program month February is getting parsed as '33'. For other months it works correctly.

```
// Stores the inputed date which needs to be converted
String date = "2/2/2016";

// Create DateFormat object for the inputed format.
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy");

// Convert the String date to Date object using inputed format
Date d = df.parse(date);        

// Create date object for format in which the inputed date needs to be converted
df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMDDYYYY");


// Convert the inputed date
String convertedDate = df.format(d);

System.out.println(convertedDate);
```

Output is 02332016

Answer (score 1):

You should use letter `d` (small case) in `new SimpleDateFormat(...)`. Letter `D` (upper case) is for the number of the day in the year. This is why you get 33 because 2 February 2016 is the 33th day in the year.

Answer (score 1):

You should use "dd" for date. Try replacing your code with

```
 df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddYYYY");
```

If you would like to look at the documentation of SimpleDateFormat here is the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Replace upper-cased `D` with lower-cased `d`:

```
// Create date object for format in which the inputed date needs to be converted
df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddYYYY");
```

And next time just read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

please find below code

// Stores the inputed date which needs to be converted

```
String date = "2/2/2016";

        // Create DateFormat object for the inputed format.
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy");

        // Convert the String date to Date object using inputed format
        Date d;
        try {
            d = df.parse(date);
            // Create date object for format in which the inputed date needs to be converted
            df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddYYYY");


            // Convert the inputed date
            String convertedDate = df.format(d);

            System.out.println(convertedDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

output: `02022016`

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why all answers presented so far overlook the second bug (using the weekbased year Y instead of correct y which can cause trouble near the begin of calendar year) so the right code must look like:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy");
Date d = df.parse("2/2/2016");        
df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy");
String convertedDate = df.format(d);
System.out.println(convertedDate); // 02022016
```

It is important to understand that pattern symbols are case-sensitive and change the meaning with case.

- d = day-of-month (02)
- D = day-of-year (33 = 31 days in January + 2 days in February)
- y = year-of-era
- Y = week-based-year which is not the same as calendar year around year change (example: 2nd of January 2016 using Y yields the year 2015!!!)